# Solving a problem with constant objective in Worhp faster

Tags: constants, worhp

I have a problem in Worhp with a constant objective. For this particular problem, it is only relevant to minimise the constraint violations.

Worhp indeed finishes the optimisation with the message "Optimal Solution Found (objective appears to be constant)”.

My question is: is there a way to tell Worhp up front that the objective function is constant, so it can be more efficient (faster) in finding the solution? Are there parameters in the worhp.xml that I can adjust to solve the problem faster?

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer to my own question. The FeasibleOnly parameter instructs Worhp to stop the optimisation once a feasible point is found.

A classical case of RTFM.... sorry!